# "DESC TABLE_NAME" command in Oracle is not working with pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g R2 and i have been trying to execute the below given pl/sql procedure :-

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
TABLENAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'TABLE_NAME';
BEGIN
DESC TABLENAME;  
END;
/
```

Or

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    DECLARE
    TABLENAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'TABLE_NAME';
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DESC TABLENAME';  
    END;
    /
```

I tried everything but continuously getting the error.
Please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: `DESC` is a SQL\*Plus command, not a SQL command. You can't use it in a PL/SQL block (or outside of SQL\*Plus)

Answer (score 2):

If you have read access to user_tab_columns view, then this will return same. Verified just now.

```
          SELECT 
          column_name "Name", 
          nullable "Null?",
          concat(concat(concat(data_type,'('),data_length),')') "Type"
          FROM user_tab_columns
          WHERE table_name='TABLE_NAME'
```

Source: http://ss64.com/ora/desc.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
TABLENAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'TABLE_NAME';
BEGIN
DESC TABLENAME;  
END;
```

You are misunderstanding the use of DESC. DESC in SQL*PLUS Command Describes an Oracle Table, View, Synonym, package or Function. You cant use it inside a pl sql block.

Since it is not clear what you are trying to do, I am ASSUMING you just want to print the string stored in the variable.You can just use dbms_output.put_line(). try this

```
DECLARE
TABLENAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'TABLE_NAME';
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLENAME);  
END;
```

Comment: Need to add an end-of-file character `/` at the end, on a new line - without it, neither of these procedures will run.  Otherwise this is a great answer and would upvote it.

Comment: yes it will. but if i have another pl/sql block in the same worksheet, that is where i have to use '/'. and mind you, my answer is not a procedure. its just a pl/sql block. try running it in sql developer.

Comment: Nope - and that is where I was running it, and why I made my comment.

Comment: its working fine with me even without the '/' in the end since its not a "procedure". I just use '/' this whenever I have multiple blocks in a worksheet to compile to separate them from one another. and again, SQL Developer is different from SQL*Plus.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not in a procedure - not the issue.  Issue is you're right, it's SQL Developer vs. SQL* Plus. I've since found it seems to depend what the contents are for the `DECLARE..BEGIN...END` in order to run without an EOF character in SQL Developer. The 1st block doesn't run in SQL Developer because `DESC` is only a SQL* Plus command, not because of `/` not being there. 2nd block runs as-is. With SQL*Plus, though, it always requires `/` for either block.

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  FOR cursor1 IN (SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES where OWNER='ABC' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor1.TABLE_NAME);
      FOR cursor2 IN (select * from cols where TABLE_NAME=cursor1.TABLE_NAME ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME)
        LOOP     
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cursor2.COLUMN_NAME);
        END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: Add an end-of-file character `/` at the end, on a new line - without it, this would not run.  But otherwise this is a great answer and would upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'desc '||table_name
from all_tables
order by 1
```